# ng-file-uploadを使用した画像のアップロードについて

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

JavaScriptベースのフロントエンドアプリケーションとして AnuglarJS を使用して 
サーバ側のデータを操作する為にバックエンドAPIを Rails で構築しているのですが、 
ng-file-uploadを採用した画像のアップロードが上手く出来なくて困っています。

Shop(1) <-> Item(n)

1件のShopに複数のItemが紐付いている状態で、Shopのedit画面で画像のアップロードを実装しています。 
itemリストのループの中でそれぞれのitemに画像を登録させたいですが、ループの中では適切にアップロードができません。 
(厳密にはcontrollerの $scope.upload = (files) -> が呼び出されません。。)

また、現状ではそれぞれのitemごとに画像を設定することができなくて詰まっています。。 
APIを通してDBには正しく格納できているのでページをリロードすればきちんと表示されるのですが、 
img ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-default-src="" ngf-accept="'image/*'" 
がすべてのinputに対して共通のために、関係のないitemのimgが上書きされていしまいます。

一度に複数の画像アップロードや画像以外のアップロードは求めていなく、 
いたってシンプルなものをつくろうとしているのですがなかなか上手くいきません... 
どうかご教授いただけますと嬉しいです。

application.js

```
//= require angular.min
//= require angular-resource.min
//= require ng-file-upload.min
//= require ng-file-upload-shim.min
//= require app
//= require_tree .
```

controller.coffee

```
angular.module('kapiyva').controller "ArticleEditController", ($scope, Upload, Shop, Item) ->

  $scope.init = ->

  $scope.$watch 'files', ->
    $scope.upload $scope.files
    return

  $scope.upload = (files) ->
    if files and files.length
      alert "success"
      i = 0
      while i < files.length
        file = files[i]
        $scope.upload = Upload.upload(
          url: '/api/shops/1/items'
          method: 'POST'
          # shop_idを動的に渡せていないので一時的にベタ書きしています
          fields: 'item[shop_id]':'1'
          file: file
          fileFormDataName: 'item[image]')
        i++
      return
```

edit.html.slim

```
# ループの外では適切にアップロードされる
section
  p select file:
  input type="submit" value="ファイルを選択" ngf-select="" ng-model="files"
  img ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-default-src="" ngf-accept="'image/*'"
section
  p select file:
  input type="submit" value="ファイルを選択" ngf-select="" ng-model="files"
  img ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-default-src="" ngf-accept="'image/*'"
section
  p select file:
  input type="submit" value="ファイルを選択" ngf-select="" ng-model="files"
  img ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-default-src="" ngf-accept="'image/*'"

# ループの中では $scope.upload = (files) -> が呼ばれない...
ul ng-repeat="item in shop.items"
  p select file:
  input type="submit" value="ファイルを選択" ngf-select="" ng-model="files"
  img ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-default-src="" ngf-accept="'image/*'"
```

Comment: 解決策では無いのですが、 **controllerの $scope.upload = (files) -> が呼び出されません。。** については、 `ng-repeat` が新規に `scope` を作成するため、親に定義した `upload` は呼ばれないのだと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngf-change`を使用して`$parent.upload`を呼んでみるのはどうでしょうか？

```
.container
  ul
    li(ng-repeat='item in items')
      p {{item.name}}
      input(type="submit" value="ファイルを選択" ngf-select ngf-change="$parent.upload(item, $files)" ng-model="files")
      br
      img(ngf-src="files[0]" ngf-default-src="" ngf-accept="'image/*'")
```

Controller（抜粋）

```
# これは不要
# $scope.$watch 'files', ->
#     $scope.upload $scope.files
#     return

$scope.upload = (item, files) ->

  # ファイル未選択の場合は何もしない
  if !(files and files.length)
    return

  console.log 'id:' + item.id
  console.log files[0]

  Upload.upload({
      url: 'xxx/xxx',
      file: files[0]
  }).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      console.log 'file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data
  ).error((data, status, headers, config) ->
      console.log 'error status: ' + status
  )
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。記述いただいた流れでなんとかアップロードできるように修正できました（ちなみにこちらをuploadではなくupdateとして既存のit‌​emを上書きする形でimageを保存しようと思った際はcontrollerの修正だけでは実現するのが困難ですかね...？）。ngf-changeと$parentの使い方‌​が大変勉強になりました。ずっと詰まって悩んでいたのですごく助かりました。ありがとうございました。